# O cache do navegador continua funcionando junto com o cachê do service worker?

Tags: javascript, cache, service-worker

Eu estou criando um service worker para um pwapp

Consegui gerenciar o cachê através do serviceworker porém ao atualizar os arquivos do pwapp, ocorreu o seguinte:

O serviceworker apagou o cachê antigo normalmente, mas ao carregar os novos arquivos, eles ainda estavam de alguma forma salvos em outro cachê do navegador, e por isso as alterações não foram carregados...

Para constar: em outro teste, eu desabilitei o cachê no devtools do chrome, e dessa forma funcionou tudo corretamente, com o service worker salvando os arquivos no seu proprio cachê, e quando deixei offline pelo devtools, os arquivos foram carregados corretamente a partir do cachê.

A questão é: existem dois cachês separados ou eu estou equivocado? Se sim, como faço para usar apenas o cachê do service worker, desabilitando o outro?

Estou usando os códigos do link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/?hl=pt-br

Comment: Independentemente de onde esteja rodando o código, a API Cache é a mesma, então, não, não existe dois caches separados. O mais provavel que tenha acontecido é que o cache foi apagado depois das requisições terem sido feitas e respondidas com os arquivos antigos